# Cross Stack Reference in AWS for SPA & API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I have below mentioned two AWS services

- **Stack 1:** Api Gateway + Lambda ( Serverless )
- **Stack 2:** SPA ( Single page application ) using AWS S3.

I want to expose either `Stack 1` alone **'or'** deploy both `Stack 1 & Stack 2` so both stacks can talk to each other seemlessly.

**My current solution:**
I am thinking to use `Cross Stack reference` (Using Export/Import) so that `Stack 1` will output its `URL` such that it can be referred in future ( If i want to deploy `Stack 2` in future).

**My Question:**

1. How to tie API and SPA together ?
2. Though i know how to refer `Cross Stack`'s Exported `URL` value in SPA (AWS S3) but i am not sure how to make my code ( `index.html` ) in AWS S3 dynamic such that it will call `Stack 1`'s API.

**UPDATE:**
Wondering if my question is clear enough. Another way of asking my question would be "How can i use a `URL` spitted out from `Stack 1` inside a Javascript/Ruby etc... code ?". I know how to refer `URL` inside another cloudformation template but not inside code.

Comment: Can you move the API Gateway resource to your Stack 2?

Comment: I don't it would be best for my scenario as i am trying to expose `Stack 1` and `Stack 1 + Stack 2` as two different services. In situations where i just need `Stack1` .. your suggestion will be apt for my case. @yorodm

Comment: BTW what do you suggest if i move it to Stack 2 ? @yorodm

Comment: Ok, if you want to expose Stack 1 as let's say a REST API and use it from Stack 2 by exporting its API Gateway URL you need something from this side that translates that into something you can always know. Either another API Gateway or an Appsync endpoint with a bunch of HTTP Resolvers

Comment: I don't think i follow your comment. What is your suggestion to solve the problem ?

Comment: since `URL` is exported from Stack 1. You can create another enpoint in `Stack 2` (either Api Gateway or Appsync) that point to it. Then make the endpoint in Stack 2 available via some DNS name

Comment: But the problem here is how to point to a `URL` from `Stack 2` in first place. How to have my code in `Stack 2` to talk to `Stack 1`'s URL is the main question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188374/discussion-between-yorodm-and-rahul-dess).

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

1. As you mentioned, if you are able to export the API Base Endpoint or better if you can export the variables `api-id`, `region` and `stage`, then you can dynamically build the URL in the SPA code.

The base endpoint would be

```
https://{api-id}.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/{stage}
```

and make HTTP requests using an AJAX library.

**The most important thing in this method is to rebuild and deploy `stack-2` each time you remove and deploy `stack-1`**

2. If you do not want to deploy `stack-2` every time `stack-1` is changed, then map the API service to a custom domain. i.e. your API endpoint can be mapped to a Custom URL such as `https://api.example.com` and each time the stack is rebuilt, the new endpoint would be mapped to the existing custom URL, protecting your `stack-2` from failure. Ofcourse, in your stack-2 you would be doing HTTP requests to `https://api.example.com` or `https://api.example.com/myservice` and so on.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html

If you are using `serverless-framework` you can refer to this answer on how to achieve this solution: https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/2074#issuecomment-323370777

Comment: I am interested in how to do part `dynamically build the URL in the SPA code.`. 
Let's say i get the imported `URL` from `Stack 1`. I know how to reference that `URL` inside cloudformation template, But How can i use that `URL` variable inside my html/js code ?

Comment: If you are using JS and want to handle this dynamically on frontend code, then you can use AWS JS SDK. You can create an AWS instance and look for exported values from aws.cloudformation. Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK

Comment: You can also do static builds locally, where you access the exported variables from the builder script (e.g. you can use boto3 for python scripts). The URL will then be hardcoded into the html. This would mean you have to redeploy this stack eachtime the API stack is redeployed

Comment: oh .. Any example snippet for doing this functionality ? Because my question is on how to use the exported variable in code. I am stuck at this point